# Spark: How to use nested data from different dataframes to find match (Scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I have "doorsDF" var DataFrame, as follows (simplified):

```
+-----+-----+-----+------+
| door|    x|    y| usage|
+-----+-----+-----+------+
|    a|   32|   14|     5|
|    b|   28|   53|     1|
|    c|   65|   94|    23|
|    d|   68|   53|     1|
|    e|   51|   94|    12|
+-----+-----+-----+------+
```

and I have "peopleDF" var DataFrame as follows (simplified):

```
+-------+-----+
| person|    x|
+-------+-----+
|    foo|   30|
|    bar|   66|
|  Morty|   52|
+-------+-----+
```

only showing top 3 rows

**I want to make a baseline 'prediction' of what door(s) will a person use to enter the building. What matters is if a person is within 5 'x' units.**

For instance, foo would walk through doors 'a' and 'b'. Morty would walk through doors 'c' and 'd'. and bar would walk through only door 'e'.

Progress so far: attempted to add a "potential exits" column to the second DataFrame by using:

```
val sequence = doorsDF.select("door").rdd.map(r => r(0)).collect().mkString(",")
val doorColumn = lit(sequence)    
peopleDF = peopleDF.withColumn("potentialDoors", doorColumn)
```

The result (new peopleDF):

```
+-------+-----+---------------+
| person|    x| potentialDoors|
+-------+-----+---------------+
|    foo|   30|      a,b,c,d,e|
|    bar|   66|      a,b,c,d,e|
|  Morty|   52|      a,b,c,d,e|
+-------+-----+---------------+
```

But now when I tried to use an udf to loop through the potential doors, use their names to filter the doorsDF and get its x value to compare to the x value in peopleDF, I get a nullpointer exception. I have read that it is because I am trying to used filter in a nested situation.

There must be a better way to do this with the functions available, maybe not even resorting to udf or rdd, but it eludes me. I have been at it for a long time.

Also, the reason why I initially chose to have a string of potentialDoors (as opposed to an array) is because I found it easier to handle for my purpose, but I am open to suggestions.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this provisionally by doing the following:

- Turning the doorsDF DataFrame into an array of rows. Lets say doorsArr
- When applying UDF to peopleDF in order to add potentialDoor column, I looped through that doorsArr array INSTEAD of trying to filter/query the doors DF.

Now I was able to reduce the "potential" pool successfully.

I can't help but feel this is still inefficient and it required some hard-coding. So I'm still open to cleaner suggestions! I want to get better at using the provided functions. Thanks for taking the time to read.